# Android icon generator in any color

Tags: android

I am trying to use this:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html

To generate icons of different colors. Red for now.

The problem is that the generator is not picking the color if I leave the Size(Optional) to default 24 dip.

But it picks the color if I keep increasing it. Even strange thing is that the drawable types which pick the color depends on the size.
e.g: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Faction_accessibility.svg&size=200&padding=0&color=f44336%2C100&name=ic_action_accessibility

> 1. If the size is 24 dip - None picks the color
> 2. If the size is 100 dip - Only xxxhdpi and xxhdpi picks the color rest are black
> 3. if the size is max i.e 200 dip - Every thing picks the color but mdpi(which is still black)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exactly same Problem before.
in

> https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html

The selected color is not picked by the drawable, this is an issue while using Google Chrome ,i.e, chrome raises a security exception while opening that url while **Firefox** doesn't. for that website use `Mozilla Firefox` you will get your job done

Comment: I took me 2 days to figure out that in my case.